# React Redux - Load more infinite items with x items at a time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using React - Redux to display search results. I do not want to display all results and want to keep performance as good as possible.

This is how I get and display the results:

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      searchedOnce: true
    })
    const apiSearchURL = `/api/search/religion/${this.state.formValues.religion}/gender/${this.state.formValues.gender}`
    get(apiSearchURL, { maxContentLength: 400 })
    .then((searchResults) => {
      this.props.dispatch(getSearchResults(searchResults))
    })
  }

...
...
  render() {
    const { users } = this.props
    let map_usersList = users.data && users.data.map((userlist => (
      <SearchResult key={userlist.id} {...userlist} />
    )))
...
...
...
    <ul>
    { this.state.searchedOnce
      ?  map_usersList
      :  <SearchNoResult/>
    }

    </ul>
```

How can I display map_usersList - 5 items at a time with load more button and show a message  "No more items" at the end when there are no more results ?.

I am using Redux. When the search results come up the state has all the results. I am thinking the first time the state should only have 5 items ? I have never worked with React/Redux so need some tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply slice the users.data to display only the number of users you want to display at a time. Assuming that you want to display 5 more users on each click of a 'Load More' button, you can go by the following code:

```
 constructor(){
    this.state = {
         ....
         pageNo: 1,
     }
 } 
 ....
 render() {
   const { users } = this.props
   let map_usersList = users.data && users.data.slice(0, this.state.pageNo * 5).map((userlist => (
     <SearchResult key={userlist.id} {...userlist} />
    )))
 ....
 ....
 loadMoreClick() {
   this.setState({
     pageNo: this.state.pageNo + 1,
   })
 }
 ....
 ....

<ul>
  { this.state.searchedOnce
    ?  map_usersList
    :  <SearchNoResult/>
  }
  {
    this.state.pageNo * 5 >= 400 //(maxContentLength) 
    ? 'No more items' : <LoadMoreButton />
  }
</ul>
```